# How to prepare a dynamic SOQL in Talend?

Tags: apex, integration, data, data-migration

I want to setup a ETL job in Talend to query intersection of data between two salesforce prod environments.

And here is what I want to do:

1. Query list of accounts from one salesforce org.
2. Take a column from above step and pass that to the next step and query from the second salesforce org.

But how do I construct SOQL query for the second step referencing output of first step:

Here is screenshot showing two components:

[image]

How do I connect these two components so that the filter condition for second component uses rows returned from first component.

Talend supports Manual input of SOQL query but I am not sure how to reference the results returned in the previous step:

[image]

**Note:** : I know this question is for more suited for talend community but as it involves Salesforce I am taking my chances here. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are just looking for a intersection of the two data sets based on a field? if so, just query both orgs and run them into a tMap. And if not maybe you can clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve with the second query.

Comment: I could use tmap to find intersection but that way I will be querying all the accounts from second salesforce with out any filter. Without any filter we are talking about 5 million rows. Because of this reason I want to apply filter condition before querying data from second salesforce environment. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @JesseMilburn, I found that this question(https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=25906) on talend forum is similar to what I am looking for. Do you know of any workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: @Jay Did you look at this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126091/talend-and-dynamic-soql ? if your requirement is like as mine, after querying from the first org, store the list of Ids to be queried from the second org in Talend global variable and reference that in the second component SOQL.