# Talend and Dynamic SOQL

Tags: integration, talend

Does anyone know if Talend can use dynamic soql so that a 'only retrieve sobjects that have systemmoddate > last time we synced' retrieval can be done ?

I've tried using variables but the connector doesnt seem to like the idea of merging them into a manual SOQL string.

I dont see how Talend is a viable piece of middleware if it cannot do this, so interested to learn from those who've managed it!

Cheers

Comment: I asked the same question few weeks ago and no answer yet : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122422/how-to-prepare-a-dynamic-soql-in-talend?noredirect=1#comment173552_122422

Answer (score 1):

I've sorted this and yes can do it.

You need to create a global var, in my example its LASTACCOUNTQUERY. Populate this prior to executing the query, likely via a tJava component.

Then, in your connection metadata, define the SOQL query manually.  When you want to add one of your merge fields, use CTRL+SPACE to access a list of available options.

Your result will end up something like the following:

"select id,name from account where systemmodstamp >" + ((String)globalMap.get("LASTACCOUNTQUERY")) + " order by systemmodstamp DESC limit 100"